# Display hyperlink value in kendo ui grid column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created columns dynamically in the kendo ui grid. The data displayed in the columns could be date , string integer, hyperlinks or any other type.

Data in the column can be integer/hyperlink at the same time. Means for a particular record the data in column can be integer. For next record same column can have a hyperlink value.
I have created fields and added that in the grid.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set a function against the template of the column you wish to format and conditionally return the content of what you want to appear.

This could look something like this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { Id:1, val: "value" },
    { Id:"http://google.com", val: "another value" }
  ]
});

$(function () {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      {
        field: "Id",
        template: function (dataItem) {
          if (typeof dataItem.Id == "string") {
            return "<a href=\"" + dataItem.Id + "\">" + dataItem.Id + "</a>";
          } else {
            return dataItem.Id;
          }
        }
      }],
    dataSource: dataSource
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I have created array of columns and pushing column titles and field in that array and then passing the array to columns property of kendo ui grid. So how can I use the above code with respect to that.

Comment: Also, say for example I will have value in my column as http://www.test.com,test. So in this case , I want the text to be displayed in the column as test that is after comma (,) and on clicking on it that should open the url as http://www.test.com

Comment: @user2117983 You will have to add more information and example code of what you have currently to the original question above for you to get a more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks @boniestlawyer. I am using the above mentioned code as you have given in your example. colHeader.push({ title: title,
                            field: fieldName,
                            width: colWidth,
                            template: function (dataItem) {                                            
                                            return "<a href=\"" + val[0] + "\">" + val[1] + "</a>";

                                        }
                         });

Comment: Update your actual question with a sample of the code you are having the issue with